# how to configure node.js to log events with date

Tags: node.js, date, logging

So far I only could get logs without dates. How to configure the logs to automatically do this?

Or, is there a better logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) is great for this! You can get logs into json, mongodb, etc.

Alternatively, you could write your own log function

Comment: any "best practice" to ask express.js to use winston instead of the usual one?